# Can we change the region of SSH certificate in AWS or move from one region to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

Actually i have a AWS SSH certificate in N.virginia and i have all the setup for the environment in oregon.

What,which type and why the region matters & not matters in some AWS services?

Comment: is it `SSH` Certificate or `SSL` Certificate ?

Comment: Are you talking about an SSH key used to login to an Amazon EC2 instance, or an SSL certificate used to authenticate HTTPS websites?

Comment: I am extremely sorry for late response but yeah !! I was asking about SSL certificate with we generally use to authenticate the user to login in any website,so was using that with the AWS services.